# How to set selected or default value in select2 yii2?

Tags: yii2, default, jquery-select2, selected

How to set selected or default value in select2 yii2?
i've tried using `'value' => $myvalue` and `'initValue' => $myValue`

Is there any solution? Thank You.

I've just found solution.
here if you want to set default value or selected value for select :

```
<?php $model->group = yourdefaultValue ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'group')->label('Group Name')->widget(Select2::classname(),
[
     'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Group::find()->all(),'id','name', 'kategori'),
     'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Phone Number'],
     'pluginOptions' => [
           'allowClear' => true,
           'minimumInputLength' => 2,
     ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: In your case you should set value for `$model->group`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'group')->label('Group Name')->widget(Select2::classname(),
    [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Group::find()->all(),'id','name', 'kategori'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Phone Number', 'value' => 1],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'minimumInputLength' => 2,
        ],
    ]);
?>
<?php $form::end()?>
```

You just need set default value in selection.

```
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Phone Number',
```

> 'value' => $model->id

```
]
```

Comment: It's not work. The code i've posted have been worked. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had same situation. But adding 'value' key solved my problem.

```
Select2::widget([
   'name' => ['1'=> 'A', '2' => 'B', '3' => 'C'],
   'value' => [1,3], // value to initialize
   'data' => $data
]);
```

Above example will automatically select A & C.

Perhaps if you could add your sample data structure here then it will be helpful for us to help you.

Please see the link for more details: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets/issues/87#issuecomment-46200711